# It's possible to call html and css tags inside a text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First question here! So, i'm at the beginning of my studies and i have searched on Google and didn't found anything about this scenario:

I'm developing a website that contains a lot of  files (over 500 on the same page, it's a list of cards). If i write all the tags of those images the code will be a mess.

I would like to know if would be possible for example to create a ".txt" file with all the img tags inside it, and make a call through JavaScript or jQuery, so that they are displayed on the screen. For example:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="all-cards">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/black/fatom-fleet-captain.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/blue/kopala-warden-of-waves.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/green/colossal-dreadmaw.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/red/bonded-horncrest.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/white/adanto-vanguard.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/multicolored/admiral-beckett-brass.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/artifacts/pirate's-cutlass.png">
                <img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/lands/unknow-shores.png">
            </div>
```

Put all those  on a .txt and call on that page "cards-database.html".

Thank you!

Comment: If you're planning to reuse the list of images across multiple pages it would make sense to store the URLS as JSON data (not a .txt file) and access it via ajax calls.  But if this is just for one single page there's no particular advantage to doing that.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you about your answer! I'm planning to do only on that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, store them in a JSON file on your server:

```
[
 "black/fatom-fleet-captain",
 "blue/kopala-warden-of-waves",
 "green/colossal-dreadmaw"
]
```

Then make a request for that file using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (in my opinion, slightly shorter than `$.ajax`), iterate over the list and build the image tags with [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
fetch('list-of-images.json')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(images => {
   for (let card of images) {
     $('#all-cards').append(`<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">`)
   }
 }
})
```

But as Daniel noted, there is no particular advantage to doing this. In fact, you'll take a performance *hit* because you have to load the page, then load the list of images, then start getting the images.

A better idea is just to store the array directly in the script file that does the appending loop, like:

```
const images = [
  "black/fatom-fleet-captain",
  "blue/kopala-warden-of-waves",
  "green/colossal-dreadmaw"
];

for (let card of images) {
    $('#all-cards').append(`<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">`)
}
```

**Additional**:

Don't store your entries twice. I was going to propose this in the original answer but got lazy.

Just store your cards as an object *whose keys are the colour*, and the card names as an array within each colour:

```
const cards = {
    "black": [
        "fatom-fleet-captain"
    ],
    "blue": [
        "kopala-warden-of-waves"
    ],
    "green": [
        "colossal-dreadmaw"
    ]
};
```

Then you can get the cards of just one colour:

```
// Get all the black cards
for (const card of cards.black) console.log(`black/${card}.png`)
```

Or you can flatten the object to get all cards in one array, here I've use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and an extra array for clarity:

```
const all_cards = [];
for (let colour in cards) {
  for (let card of cards[colour]) all_cards.push(`/${colour}/${card}.png`)
}
```

Adjust as needed.

You may be looking at that [`cosnt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) in `const all_cards = []` and wondering how that could work. Note that `const` prevents *reassignment* (meaning with `=`) not operations like pushing to an array, or mutating object properties.

Comment: Does `fetch` auto convert a response to json if it ends with `.json`? Otherwise you need `then(response => response.json()).then(images ...`

Comment: @xdumaine That's a good point: it does not. I'm too deep in angular auto-parsing land. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and thanks about the answer! :)

It worked like a charm, thank you! But i have another problem: i'm working with tabs (Bootstrap) and this script makes only the active tab show the content. How we can show the another tabs the content? Here's my code:

`<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="all-cards">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="black-cards">
</div>`

Etc.. If i'm not asking too much, can you explain me with details how this trick works? I'm a newbie on JS/jQuery. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry @msanford, im still getting used to stackoverflow community! Thanks :D

Here is a screeshot of the code to make it easier:
[Code Screenshot](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/252/588/original/CORAL.png?1516138512)

The problem is the other tabs, they don't have content because i delete the lines of the <img> on code, they still work on active/main tab (All Cards). How can i make their appear again on another tabs?

Comment: @AlexandrePedroza No need to apologize. Welcome to the community! You should make sure that if you make another question, don't post screenshots of code, post the code as text, just like you did above. Check out [mcve] and [ask] just to re-familiarize yourself with how to ask a question people will be able to help you with.

Comment: @msanford hey i got it! I just created another lines on script  and changed the #id in the last part of the script to another #id: 

`<script>
  const all_cards = [
  "black/fatom-fleet-captain",
  "blue/kopala-warden-of-waves"
  ];

  const black_cards = [
  "black/fatom-fleet-captain"
  ];

for (let card of all_cards) {
   $('#all-cards').append(`<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">`)
  }
  for (let card of black_cards) {
   $('#black-cards').append(`<img src="../img/cards/en-gb/xln-cards/${card}.png">`)
  }`

Thanks a lot msanford!

Comment: @AlexandrePedroza Cool! Glad you got it working. See update for a slightly 'cleaner' way of doing that.